# AWS best method to ssh between servers in private subnet

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

Is it just normal Linux user creation at this point?

I have my NAT and Bastion set up to login with SSH forwarding:

```
ssh -A ec2-user@bastionhost
ssh ec2-user@privateSubnetServer
```

What's the best method for handling ssh and users at this point between hosts in the private subnet?

I can't set up or connect to a directory service at this point.

Comment: Your question isn't particularly clear. In short, an EC2 server is a standard Linux server, if you require more users you create them the same way you do on any Linux server.

Comment: @Tim I think I was over thinking it. Answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they’re both in the same subnet then they’ll nearly always have connectivity. That gives you two approaches:

You could edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config on the server to make sure that password authentication is permitted and then use passwd to give a password to the user account on the server you’ll be logging into. Those two steps do, however, introduce a level of vulnerability.

The better solution would be to (securely) copy a private .pem key to the client that you can use to permit passwordless SSH access to the server. You can then SSH in using: ssh -i keyname.pem username@If they’re both in the same subnet then they’ll nearly always have connectivity.